# io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is less than expected - expected 5 but was 4 ERROR

Tags: android, realm

ERROR - Realm-Android - I started using Realm for my new project I am getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field count is less than expected - expected 5 but was 4... I googled  but not found correct solution. can anyone guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you changed your Realm model class without adding a schemaVersion/migration to your RealmConfiguration ?

Comment: this happens if you add new fields to your existing Realm schema, but you can specify `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` on your `RealmConfiguration` for during development so you do not need to worry about it

Comment: You might find some help in https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Comment: I delete primary key from my model... I used **deleteIfMigrationNeeded()** on my RealmConfuguration, but still facing the problem.

Comment: RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .name("example.app")
                        .schemaVersion(0)
                        **.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()**
                        .build();
Added the deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() and it works for me.